# jquery variable on .animate margin

Tags: jquery, variables, margin

I need to use "wbanner" to move a div, but marginLeft do not recognize the variable as a value

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var wbanner = (screen.width/2)-175;
    $('.banner').hide().show(1000).animate({marginLeft : "+=$('.wbanner')"}, 3000).css('color', '#85bbd7');

)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to select a variable just use it like this:

```
function() { 

var wbanner = (screen.width/2)-175;
$('.banner').hide().show(1000).animate({marginLeft : "+=" + wbanner}, 3000).css('color', '#85bbd7');
```

Comment: "+=" + wbanner + "px" maybe

Comment: Nice, but what if i want to animate the TOP margin the same way?